# Not able to send request for HTTPS post server using CURL

Tags: c, curl

Iam writing a C program to interact with HTTPs server. Server is expecting the data without 
any assignments(Ex: normally a request can be "https://xz.aspx?name=google" where as is it
possible to send the name "https://xz.aspx?google"). Currently server is getting an entry
log for my request but not able to fetch request data.

1.Is it possible to send a value with out assignment?
2.Will .net look for default assignments?
3.Is there anything else to probe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you're sending is just whatever you put in the query part of the request-uri in the HTTP request.

That data can be almost anything you like (as long as it is using letters that are valid according to RFC2616). The "assignments" concept is not something HTTP knows or uses, it is just a common way for clients and servers to deal with the data.

so... Yes, you can send a value "without assignment" with curl. Weather the receiver will like it or understand it is a completely different matter.